# Insert Schema into MongoDB with HTTP post

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, postman

I need to insert new Schema into MongoDB.The only point of access to the database that I have is through http.post request.
I am currently trying to do it with POSTMAN, but I cannot figure out the syntax I need to send in order to create a schema. This is what I have if someone has ideas I would be grateful for your input.

```
var TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
title:{type:String,required:true}, 
instructions:{type:String,required:true}, 
repeatWeekDay:{type:Number,required:false}, 
medication:[medicationSchema], 
reading:[{ 
   readingType:{type:String,required:true}, 
   measureType:{type:String,required:true}, 
   measureValue:{type:String,required:true}, 
   measureUnits:{type:String,required:true}, 
   measureFormat:{type:String,required:true} 
}], 
alerts:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Alert'}], 
plans:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Plan'}], 
createdAt:{type: Date, default: Date.now }, 
createdBy:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'}, 
updatedAt:{type: Date, default: Date.now }, 
updatedBy:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're laboring under a misapprehension.

`mongoose` is a JavaScript library/module that enforces structured interaction with the `mongodb` datastore using Schemas, Types, etc. where a Schema object simply provides necessary programmatic intelligence to its validation function, and is not a data format itself. In other words, internally a mongoose Schema is a function not a data interchange format.

`mongodb` is a schema-less data storage engine that gleefully accepts any properly formatted JSON document for storage.

I can imagine very few reasons to store a data schema in `mongodb`.